# Projection in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, timelion

Using Kibana, I would like to make a projection of my annual turnover.
I would like to make a projection of the turnover (total amount excl. tax with discount) on a XX platform, Shopify for example) based on the sliding average of the last 30 days.

I'll run this query

```
SELECT moving_average(sum("montantht_total_avec_remise"), 30) * (365 - DAY_OF_YEAR(NOW()) + 1) FROM commandeindex_* WHERE timefield = 'date_vendu' AND $__timeFilter(date_vendu)
```

But I keep getting the same error, namely :

> The Formula SELECT moving_average("montantht_total_avec_remise", 30, 'linear') FROM commande * WHERE plateforme = 'priceminister' AND timefield = 'date_vendu' GROUP BY time(1d) cannot be parsed

do you happen to know where my error came from?

If I can, I'd like to break down the request by month with the different monthly budgets.

Estimation of my turnover based on my 30 last daily figures